# A bootable self-installable image of a fresh Windows installation with Norton Ghost?

Tags: disk-image, norton-ghost

I have just set up my aunt's computer with Windows, drivers and the software she needs. At some point in the future, when the computer has gotten unbearable clogged up with bloatware and stuff, I will have to do this again.

So I would like to make an image of the state of the computer now. I believe I can do this with Norton Ghost.

I can't really tell from their website (and other resources) how the image is then "re-installed", cloned onto the partition.

I was hoping that I could create a self-installable image. When first creating the image, Norton Ghost would then burn that to a dvd. In the future, my aunt can then just boot from the dvd, choose the partition to clone to, and after 30minutes of cloning, the PC is in the exact same state as it is today. Is that possible?

I don't want to buy the license to find out that this is not possible.

If not possible, could you then please explain me how the restore-cloning does happen? Is it something my untechy aunt can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If not possible, could you then please explain me how the restore-cloning does happen?
>   Is it something my untechy aunt can do?

I tried this with my parents and while I think it is extremely simple, it seems quite outside the realm of some people. Booting from a CD or DVD seems easy enough.... Until you realise that it needs to be the right side up and that you probably need to press <kbd>F12</kbd> or some other key to access a boot menu.

Next step would be selecting an image from the right place, then the right partition inside it and the right destination. Most parents seem to run away screaming at this point. They do not have 'volumes' or 'poartitions'. They have a C: drive and a D: drive. The C: drive is always full, and the D: drive unused. :-(

However doing it yourself is trivial, and I do recommend using Ghost, Acronis or CloneZilla (or any other free program) to take a image from that cleanly installed computer. Tape a bootable CD to the inside of their case (just for starting the restore program. Even a floppy disk with ghost.exe would do). Store the image either on a DVD (warning 4GB limit!) or on a small FAT partition on the harddisk. Do not mount that partition. If you use windows go to drive management and remove the assigned drive letter. That way you have a local backup, a big enough volume on which you can store it and a ready CD or pendrive to start the restore program.

Comment: lol, (right side up). I wrote a single page for my parents that had step by step (restore clone) instructions, specific to thier system, and they still could not do it, but over the phone a little hand holding worked.

Comment: I have a CD taped to the inside of my sisters computer. It boots an emulated 2.88MB floppy which contains ghost 8.3. An image is on her (not mounted) E:\ volume which is formatted with FAT so the DOS CD can read it. Restoring the OS is now trivial and just takes 20 minutes. Getting people to store the data on the D drive (labeled `DATA` where as the C: drive is labels `BOOT` seems impossible. Even though [My documents] points to D:\

Comment: Same Idea, I  cloned the "system" to the 2nd disk also, so with a bootmenu (bios) they could hop to the older clean clone in 3 steps. Without them updating the clone though, it is a retract similar to a "dell reinstall" :-( .  The clone is the computer Savior, they gotta take 10min out of thier life a month and work through it, or they might as well use the computer at the library :-)

Comment: 4GB limit? DL DVDs anyone? :) (BTW, besides cloning TeamViewer or similar is indispensable to deal with panicky calls about how the computer is broken yet again...)

Comment: Dual layer DVDs are a lot more expensive than regular ones and not every computer has a DVD player which can read them. And a modern computer might not even have any optical drive at all (No technical need for them unless you build a HTPC to play DVDs or BRs in the living room). Not that they are that expensive, but just useless.  As to teamviewer (or VNC or Dameware or any similar software): Aye. Very useful.

Answer (score 0):

First have a

```
C: (good working operating system) and
D: (data this partition will not be imaged)
```

imagex.exe is a free imaging program that is included as part of the "Windows AIK" (Automated Install Kit).

Get windows AIK and install it.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5753

### Then: (See notes below about each "Step")

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709665%28v=ws.10%29.aspx
You can skip step 3

After completing Step 2 in the 2nd link
in the "mount\windows\system32" folder
open the startnet.cmd file and add this after wpeinit
(The command below restores the image)
imagex /apply d:\goodos.wim 1 c:\

Make sure to do Step 4  ImageX

---

On the PC to image boot from the CD/DVD or USB you just created.  It will initial error because goodos.wim does not exist.  So just ignore that.

type: (captures the image)
imagex /capture c:\ d:\goodos.wim "Good Backup OS"

The next time the CD/DVD or USB is used it will find a valid goodos.wim and use it to restore the system.

The when booting from the CD/DVD or USB it will look for d:\goodos.wim and restore it to the c: drive because we added the command to the startnet.cmd file.

If the image was small enough you might be able to fit it on a DVD.  Alternatively, if you are willing to pay you can almost always find a USB stick big enough to contain everything.  You can buy 32gb and greater USB sticks so this should not be a problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it is really hard to read and understand your answer. It would raelly help if you thought more about punctuation, phrasing, structure and formatting.

Comment: @ThomasWessel I rewrote the instructions.